# Encryption using rijndael

Tags: c#

I'm quite new in programming .I wrote the below code in order to prompt the user for a password to encrypting a file, But it just work when the length of password is 8, What can I do on order to accepting any number of characters for the password?

```
 string pass = textBox2.Text.ToString();
            string password = @"" + pass + ""; 
            UnicodeEncoding UE = new UnicodeEncoding();
            byte[] key = UE.GetBytes(password);


            FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(@"c:\\users\\new", FileMode.Create);
            name = fsCrypt.Name;
            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

            CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
                RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(key, key),
                CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open);

            int data;
            while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
                cs.WriteByte((byte)data);
```

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by the line: string password = @"" + pass + ""; what are you trying to achieve by joining an emtpy string onto each end of a string, resulting in an identical string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly deriving a Key form your password with `Encoding.GetBytes()` will only work if the result of GetBytes() is a legal KeySize.

More important, it makes a very weak Key, especially as you opted for the Unicode encoding. The byte pattern in your key for "foobar" is `66 00 6F 00 6F 00 62 00 61 00 72 00`. Do you see all the 00 bytes?

The official way is to use the `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` class. Also it is probably not a good idea to use the Key as IV, I'm not entirely sure about this.

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2975472/rijndael-encryption-only-part-of-the-string-is-decrypted/2975666#2975666).

Comment: Thanks to mention it,yeah you are right it gone be a weak one.

Comment: Reusing the key as IV is indeed a bad idea. I wrote about it here: http://crazyscot.livejournal.com/304065.html

Comment: @crazyscot: Yes, thx for the links. But note that it is somewhat acceptable for encrypting short strings while avoiding the overhead of transporting Salt and IV. But it should be clearly marked and understood as weak.

Answer (score 2):

You need a function that is going to get a valid key length for Rijndael from your password, and at the moment, your use of `UnicodeEncoding.GetBytes` is only going to give this for certain discrete lengths of password, as you've discovered.

You should use another function to get a key from your password - perhaps take the byte array you have generated, and run a cryptographic hash function like SHA1 on it. SHA1 will give you a 128 bit length, like your 8 character passwords currently do, but regardless of the length of the password.

Comment: Let me see did i get it right?
You mean i should take a hash value of the password(which for sure is long enough)and then pass that as the key?

Answer (score 0):

Check out `PasswordDeriveBytes`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.passwordderivebytes(v=VS.100).aspx

You'll need a fixed salt value as well as the passed, this stops people working out the passwords from the algorithm.

It's used like this for TripleDES and should be easy to modify for Rijndael:

```
// Create a TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object.
TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tdes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();

// Create a PasswordDeriveBytes object and then create
// a TripleDES key from the password and salt.
PasswordDeriveBytes pdb = new PasswordDeriveBytes(pwd, salt);


// Create the key and set it to the Key property
// of the TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider object.
tdes.Key = pdb.CryptDeriveKey("TripleDES", "SHA1", 192, tdes.IV);
```